# Как реализовать загнутый уголок?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

[image: уголок]

Подскажите, пожалуйста как средствами CSS реализовать такой маркер? Интересует именно этот уголок скругленный. Пробовал через :after но не могу придумать как быть с прозрачностью заднего фона? Сзади находится фото:

Comment: как вариант через картинку - backgroud:url(img);

Comment: Не подходит вариант, задний фон (изображение) будет динамически меняться. Если оранжевый уголок везде будет одинаковый, то "красный" уголок может быть чем угодно. Хоть голубым небом.  Если же вы имели ввиду заменить весь маркер на png картинку, то этот вариант тоже не подходит поскольку размер текста, как и его наполнение тоже будет меняться (к примеру на другом языке)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно ваш вопрос в этом    `border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;` в `.marker:before` ?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marker {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px dashed orange;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.marker:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 50px solid #fff;
  border-right: 50px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 50px solid orange;
  border-left: 50px solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="marker">
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

для экспериментов : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/vpPEeW

Comment: Спасибо за рабочий вариант. Взял за основу, но возможно вы сможете посоветовать как быть если надо учитывать ещё и фото которое лежит ПОД маркером. (Сейчас вы просто рисуете два треугольника один из которых имеет цвет фона = общему фону (#fff) ) Как быть если общий фон это фото, которое меняется ?